# Why my Facebook profile says I have 155 friends but I'm only seeing 150? I saw fake a friend but now can't see

Tags: facebook

Why my Facebook profile says I have 155 friends but I'm only seeing 150 when I ran this
http://www.peacegig.com/facebook-apps/backup-friends/index.php?zip-request=true
I saw unknown person list as Facebook friend I can't even unfriend nor block.  What's going on with Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably people who have deactivated their accounts. They are still your "Friends" although their account is not active.

The reason for this is that When they re-activate their account, their friends are still connected. Otherwise they would have to re-add all of their friends.

Comment: You don't work with Facebook, right?  Oh well who knows?  The Facebook internals (I mean whatever they're doing to help 0bama) are as secret as the USAF X-37B.